# "at an early development stage" OR "at an early stage of development"?

Tags: phrases

When I write about software development (IT sector), what is correct term:

"at an early development stage" OR "at an early stage of development"?

Comment: Is this a correct equivalent for the second line that you've suggested "We are at an early *developmental* stage, and cant release too many details"? If wrong, would you please explain.

Comment: the context is: This choice is typically made at an early ..

Answer (score 1):

The *more* correct term depends on context. For example,

*At an early stage of development*, the technology was ruled obsolete.

or

We are *at an early development stage*, and can't release too many details.

Comment: the context is: This choice is typically made at
an early ...

Comment: Isn't it required to put a comma after 'At an early stage of development' in the sentence 'At an early stage of development the technology was ruled obsolete'?

Comment: Yes good point, the first clause is a dependent/subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are semantically the same. The latter sentence seems to flow better. There are many other ways of saying this. It's up to you to imbue nuances. If you want to place any emphasis on early timing, I would write “As soon as practicable start documentation…” On the odd occasion you'd mention about stages of development where absolutely needed. Avoid falling into the trap of repeating same phrases over and over. They lose potency with overuse.